# How to add an "Example Value" in Swagger UI using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

I want to add "Example Value" like this one    [Swagger UI - Value Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9sh3.png)

```
coreapi.Document(
        title='Flight Search API',
        url='https://api.example.org/',
        content={
            'search': coreapi.Link(
                url='/search/',
                action='get',
                fields=[
                    coreapi.Field(
                        name='from',
                        required=True,
                        location='query',
                        description='City name or airport code.'
                    ),coreapi.Field(
                        name='to',
                        required=True,
                        location='query',
                        description='City name or airport code.'
                    ),
                    coreapi.Field(
                        name='date',
                        required=True,
                        location='query',
                        description='Flight date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.'
                    )
                ],
                description='Return flight availability and prices.'
            )
     

   }
)
```

https://django-rest-framework-old-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guide/schemas/

Comment: Can you add what packages you are using for schema generation and viewing, drf version, and so on?  It would help a bit.  Also, your sample doesn't include `example` in the way I'd expect it, only descriptions.